# Replacing character pairs with characters in Java

Tags: java, loops, hex

So I have want to turn string with character pairs to a string that turns all of the same character pairs to a single letter. Like if I had String: "32 5A 5A 65 75 5A 67"
To "ABBCDBE" (32=A,5A=B,65=C,75=D,67=E). I have this script:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String viesti;
    viesti = "23 44 B0 9A 61 A4 91 12 47 A4 91 96 44 B0 BF E0 32 68 EC 96 BF 32 44 B0 CA 32 35 A4 BF 32 EC A4 61 E4 CA 61 5A 32 70 12 91 32 BC 44 12 32 9A 44 91 32 96 91 E0 32 BA CA 61 BC 32 35 CA 47 47 32 E4 44 B0 CA 32 A1 CA 47 47 44 35 32 EC A4 E8 0A CA 61 E0 32 68 EC CA 32 82 61 44 70 47 CA 52 32 35 96 91 EC 32 91 EC 96 BF 32 E8 96 82 EC CA 61 32 96 BF 32 91 EC A4 91 32 91 EC CA 32 0A CA BC 32 96 BF 32 82 61 CA 91 91 BC 32 47 44 B0 9A E0 32 20 32 35 96 47 47 32 E8 44 52 CA 32 12 82 32 35 96 91 EC 32 A4 32 70 CA 91 91 CA 61 32 CA B0 E8 61 BC 82 91 96 44 B0 32 BF EC CA 52 CA 32 A4 B0 BC 32 BF 44 44 B0 E0 32 03 44 12 61 32 BF 44 47 12 91 96 44 B0 32 96 BF 5E 32 96 9A CA 47 47 E4 E8 A1 9A 61 A1 61 E0";
    int pituus;
    pituus = viesti.length();
    int i;
    i=1;
    char luku;
    char luku2;
    char merkki;
    String hexa;
    String merkki2;
    String viesti2;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    merkki = 'A';
    while(i < pituus){
    luku = viesti.charAt(i-1);
    luku2 = viesti.charAt(i);
    if(luku2!=' ' && merkki!=(char)91){
        sb.append(luku);
        sb.append(luku2);
        hexa = sb.toString();
        sb.setLength(0);
        merkki2 = Character.toString(merkki);
        viesti2 = viesti.replace(hexa,merkki2);
          i+=3;  
          merkki++;
    }
    else {
        i+=2;
    }
    }
System.out.print(viesti2);
}
}
```

But it seems that viesti2 is only has the first pair replaced and nothing else. How to workaround this?

Comment: Watch out that you don't replace already processed elements. This could certainly happen with the `replace` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These character pairs are hexadecimal numbers, I assume?

```
// Separate the pairs into array elements
String[] pairs = viesti.split(" ");
Map<Integer, Character> codeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
char[] result = new char[pairs.length];
char curChar = 'A';
// Iterate over the pairs
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
{
    if (curChar > 'Z')
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Too many code points");
    }

    // Parse the pair as an integer
    int hex = Integer.parseInt(pairs[i], 16);

    // Add character to result set
    if (!codeMap.containsKey(hex))
    {
        codeMap.put(hex, curChar);
    }
    else curChar-=1;
    result[i] = codeMap.get(hex);

    // Increment character
    curChar++;
}
String viesti2 = new String(result);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, those pairs are hexadecimal. But I want to convert them to letters A-Z only, so that first pair and all other pairs that are the same would be A, second B, third C, and so on. This is for a substitution cipher, so the those characters doesn't really matter, but I use one program that can only handle letters A-Z. Reason there are more than 26 combinations is that ".,:!? 'space' 'uppercase' " have their own character pair. This may sound stupid, but I know what I'm doing. :D

Comment: If you want the output to only contain characters in the range [A-Z], you have three options: 1) Restrict the input (which may include throwing exceptions on bad input), 2) Omit illegal characters from the output, or 3) Transform illegal characters into legal ones (in which case you need the rules for the transformation). What is it that you're looking for?

Comment: I want to have all characters to some point turned to letters A-Z so that I have some full words to let the other program analyze, and I can maybe have some of the real letters deciphered. The other program I use is: http://www.blisstonia.com/software/WebDecrypto/index.php

Comment: After looking at your code a second time, I see that you don't simply want to convert hex codes to ASCII. I'll take a crack at your original intent in a moment.

Comment: Do I need some prepairing before running your script, because for now NetBeans gives error: Cannot find symbol Symbol: class Map

Comment: `import java.util.*;` at the top of the file, after any `package` declaration if you have one.

Comment: Okay, did so, now it gives unexpected type error on the same line.

Comment: Sorry, I've been writing too much C# recently. Change the primitive generics (`<int, char>`) to the equivalent object types (`<Integer, Character>`)

Comment: Yes, that seems to solve the problem! Now there is just a little problem anymore: curChar does increase by 1 even in the situation the letter is already presented earlier(ABCDEFGHIFG`L`BC`OPQRSLOQ`BC`YQ`... when it should be ABCDEFGHIFG`J`BC`KLMNOJKM`BC`PM`...)